Difference between least square regression line and population regression line
What is difference between least square regression line and population regression line ? For example, what is difference between predicted values b0 and b1 vs actual values B0 and B1 ? Does actual values B0 and B1 exists always in nature for every population data ?
I learned the equation for least square estimation line is based only on estimated values of b0 and b1, while for another it is based on true values B0 and B1, but how do we find it ? using mathematical line concept ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
